# SetExpressCheckout with tax, The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts

Tags: java, paypal

I have the code below to get the token from paypal but somehow paypal keeps on sending me an error saying that the total of cart item does not match the order amounts. What am I doing wrong in here?

```
                    <ebl:PaymentDetails>
                    <ebl:OrderTotal currencyID="USD">21.70</ebl:OrderTotal>
                    <ebl:TaxTotal currencyID="USD">1.70</ebl:TaxTotal>
                    <ebl:ButtonSource>PayPal_SDK</ebl:ButtonSource>
                    <ebl:PaymentDetailsItem>
                        <ebl:Name>Product A</ebl:Name>
                        <ebl:Quantity>1</ebl:Quantity>
                        <ebl:Tax currencyID="USD">1.70</ebl:Tax>
                        <ebl:Amount currencyID="USD">20.00</ebl:Amount>
                    </ebl:PaymentDetailsItem>
                </ebl:PaymentDetails>
```

If I combine the tax and  amount, it works as expected ( see example below ). I want to separate tax so that the user will know how much tax they are paying for the product.

```
                    <ebl:PaymentDetails>
                    <ebl:OrderTotal currencyID="USD">21.70</ebl:OrderTotal>
                    <ebl:ButtonSource>PayPal_SDK</ebl:ButtonSource>
                    <ebl:PaymentDetailsItem>
                        <ebl:Name>Product A</ebl:Name>
                        <ebl:Quantity>1</ebl:Quantity>
                        <ebl:Amount currencyID="USD">21.70</ebl:Amount>
                    </ebl:PaymentDetailsItem>
                </ebl:PaymentDetails>
```

Comment: I don't see full your code, but I think missing ItemTotal. Can you check it?

Comment: I'm just putting all totals inside PaymentDetails, i know it's working if i just combine the tax amount with every PaymentDetailsItem but if I separate the tax, that's where it's breaking.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so i need to include itemTotal, taxTotal and orderTotal in order for this to work.

```
                    <ebl:PaymentDetails>
                    <ebl:OrderTotal currencyID="USD">43.40</ebl:OrderTotal>
                    <ebl:ItemTotal currencyID="USD">40.00</ebl:ItemTotal>
                    <ebl:TaxTotal currencyID="USD">3.40</ebl:TaxTotal>
                    <ebl:ButtonSource>PayPal_SDK</ebl:ButtonSource>
                    <ebl:PaymentDetailsItem>
                        <ebl:Name>Product A</ebl:Name>
                        <ebl:Quantity>1</ebl:Quantity>
                        <ebl:Tax currencyID="USD">1.70</ebl:Tax>
                        <ebl:Amount currencyID="USD">20.00</ebl:Amount>
                    </ebl:PaymentDetailsItem>
                    <ebl:PaymentDetailsItem>
                        <ebl:Name></ebl:Name>
                        <ebl:Quantity>2</ebl:Quantity>
                        <ebl:Tax currencyID="USD">0.85</ebl:Tax>
                        <ebl:Amount currencyID="USD">10.00</ebl:Amount>
                    </ebl:PaymentDetailsItem>
                </ebl:PaymentDetails>
```